# Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?

Tags: bash, debian, scripting, cron

I have seen a lot of times ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280678/crontab-why-wont-it-execute-script), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342159/crontab-not-executing-script) )this question, but I didn't find the answer, so here I go.

I'm running **Debian 11**, but I guess it works the same for any Debian-like distro.

My `crontab -e` looks like:

```
...
@reboot sleep 20 && /opt/isPromscaleOnOrOff.sh
...
```

And the content of `isPromscaleOnOrOff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="promscale"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE is running"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is stopped, I will run it now"
    nohup promscale --db-name asdf1234--db-password asdf1234 --db-user asdf1234 --db-ssl-mode allow --install-extensions & >> /dev/null
    disown
fi
```

But when I restart the VM the script isn't runing, tho the cron logs in **/var/log/syslog** show the crontab starting the script.

What I wanna achieve can be easilly done **daemonizing** the process (wich I indeed did), I just wanna know why crontab doesn't start up my script.

Comment: On the one hand, you say the log shows cron running the script; on the other, you say it isn't running. In the end, we can't tell what's happening because you don't show any logs or what happens at all.

Comment: Obvious question: the script has execute permission set?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/cron/info for common cron-related errors. My guess is that promscale isn't in the PATH.

Comment: Take `user` as the login id for the user that owns this job. What recent errors are in the mailbox file `/var/mail/user`? (If it exists it will be readable as a plain text file.)

Comment: Yup, the script does has execution permissions @SimonRichter.

Comment: @roaima I don't have any MTA installed, so I can't get any info from there :-(

Comment: @Kusalananda cron logs says cron ran the script but I know the script isn't runing because it would start the promscale service, wich it doesn't

Comment: If no MTA then you should be capturing _stderr_ yourself. Try `@reboot sleep 20 && /opt/isPromscaleOnOrOff.sh >/tmp/ispromscale.log 2>&1` and take a look for errors. Also look in `nohup.log` in the user's home directory

Comment: "_I know the script isn't runing because it would start the promscale service, wich it doesn't_" that's false logic. All you know is that the service didn't start. You don't know whether or not your `cron` attempted to start it, because you haven't recorded that the script ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.