# crontab - mysqldump is using different socket

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, mysql, xampp

First, I have already permanently set the PATH directory of MySQL in my `.bashrc` so I can use it in terminal in any directory. To verify this process, I restarted my computer, open the terminal and use the command `mysql` without navigating into any directory. I can also use `mysqldump` in any directory in terminal. I am using xampp, and it was installed in `/opt/lampp/`.

I have no problem at all when using mysql or mysqldump in terminal

What I don't understand, and what I want to fix is when using mysqldump in crontab.

So I have this script on my desktop, with the filename of `mysqldump.sh`. What's inside is; `mysqldump -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log`

The problem here is the mysqldump is not working and is throwing me an error of: `mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect` which I don't understand why.

I have also tried to change the code in my script to; `(cd /opt/lampp/bin/ && mysqldump -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log)` which still no luck.

what is wrong? why the crontab is using the socket of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`? How can I fix that?

Anyway, the crontab is `*/1 * * * * /home/sfadmin/Desktop/mysqldump.sh`. This should execute mysqldump every minute.

All the configurations are the default for MySQL, I didn't put any password or anything.

**EDIT**: Let's say that the said [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script) post solves this problem, which is about setting the environment variables for the cron to use, then how come this thing work;

- Perform a clean install of ubuntu (same version)
- Install Xampp
- Setting the PATH directory of MySQL in my `.bashrc`
- Create a file `mysqldump.sh` on the desktop, and make it executable.
- Add this code in the script `mysqldump.sh`: `mysqldump -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log`
- execute `crontab -e` in terminal, and save this `*/1 * * * * /home/sfadmin/Desktop/mysqldump.sh`.

How come the same method works in a fresh install without doing the said duplicate post?

Comment: Modifications to your .bashrc are unlikely to affect cronjobs (since they don't run in an interactive shell). You mentioned in your previous [self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413841/178692) that you have an apt-installed version of mysql-server - the most likely explanation here is that cron is running that instead of the LAMPP one in /opt. Try changing `mysqldump -u root thedatabase` to `/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root thedatabase` .

Comment: I [uninstalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql) the previous `mysql-server` and verified all the configuration files which do not exist anymore. I also replaced the working directory to `/opt/lampp/bin/`(stated in my post) in my script before using the `mysqldump` command and still using that socket.

Comment: I performed a clean install of ubuntu on another machine, installed the xampp, set the environment path, and scheduled the task in crontab. Funny is it's working perfectly. The only difference here is I didn't install/uninstall `mysql-server` so no modification has been made.

Comment: so my guess is somewhere, this old socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is still configured as the default. the problem is I don't know exactly where this thing is still set. I tried to search for any `my.cnf` file in the whole computer but I only have one which is located in `opt/lampp/` I checked the socket, it's not the old one.

Comment: `cd /opt/lampp/bin/ && mysqldump` doesn't guarantee to run `/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump` is located; you'd need `cd /opt/lampp/bin/ && ./mysqldump`

Comment: @steeldriver  although I did not say it in my post, I already tried that.