# Cronjob being executed but doing nothing

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, cron

I want to use the following two cronjobs to do my backups, but they dont do anything. When I execute them manually, they do what they should do, but when I let cron do these jobs I see it in syslog but nothing happens. No backup is written or pruned and no restic log is written.

Backup Job `/etc/cron.d/restic-backup`

```
#Ansible: Backup with restic
15 3 * * * root source /root/restic.env && restic backup --verbose --tag cronjob --tag cloud.XXXX.systems /mnt/XXXX_data /opt/backup > /var/log/restic/restic-backup.log 2>&1
```

Prune Job: `/etc/cron.d/restic-forget`

```
#Ansible: Prune backups from restic
15 1 * * * root source /root/restic.env && restic forget --verbose --keep-tag no-prune --tag cronjob --keep-daily 7 --keep-weekly 4 --keep-monthly 2 > /var/log/restic/restic-forget.log 2>&1
```

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script)

Comment: Did you add these schedules in `/etc/crontab` or in a `/etc/cron.d/` file where the 6th field is a username? Do you get an email from the corn daemon with an error message? Does it work if you change `source` into `.`?

Comment: Yeah you are only redirecting the outputs / errors of the second part of your commands (after the `&&` conjunction) and it's likely the first part that's failing - because cron is executing the jobs with `/bin/sh` which doesn't recognize the `source` command

Comment: You did not check your logs. You did not research the problem. You did not attempt any experiments to identify the issue. Most likely `restic` is not in the path used by Cron. Which would be explained in the logs and emails generated.

Comment: Why are you using the "root" format in your `crontab` entry? The user specification only applies to `root`s `crontab`, `/etc/crontab`. User `crontab`s (without the user specification) are kept elsewhere.

Comment: @waltinator it applies to files in /etc/cron.d as well - from `man 8 cron` *"Support for /etc/cron.d is included in the cron daemon itself, which handles this location as the system-wide crontab spool.  This directory can contain any file defining  tasks following the format used in /etc/crontab, i.e. unlike the user cron spool, these files must provide the username to run the task as in the task definition."*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the not available command `source` in `sh` . I wasnt aware of that!