# I get permission denied for a command in an sh script, but same command works from terminal

Tags: systemd, permissions, rhel, dash

I have a service run by systemctl in RedHat 8.8. The service itself is relatively simple:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service

[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=60
ExecStart=/usr/lib/myapp/service.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/lib/myapp/service.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Sudoers file is set up so that all members of the "mygroup" are able to execute this service in the name of the "myuser":

```
%mygroup ALL = (ALL : myuser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl start myservice
```

The problem is within the service.sh file. The preamble is `#!/bin/sh`. It tries to start a JBoss instance, and execute some actions, e.g.:

```
cat /dev/null > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG
START_FILE="${JBOSS_HOME}/start_user"
ACCESS_USER="$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')"
echo "${ACCESS_USER}" > ${START_FILE}
```

Now, when I'm logged in with "myuser" over SSH, and I start this service by `sudo systemctl start myservice`, I get a bunch of permission denied errors for the above commands:

When trying to cat devnull into the JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG:

`/usr/lib/myapp/service.sh: line 82: /opt/myapp/home/domain/log/console.log: Permission denied`

When trying to print into the START_FILE:

`/usr/lib/myapp/service.sh: line 92: /opt/myapp/home/start_user: Permission denied`

The file permissions are set up correctly as far as I can tell, everything is owned by "myuser" and "mygroup":

```
ll /opt/myapp

drwrwxr-x+ 11 myuser mygroup 4096 Nov 14 20:56 home

ll /opt/myapp/home

drwxrwxr-x+ 10 myuser mygroup 4096 Nov 14 20:29 domain

ll /opt/myapp/home/domain

drwxrwxr-x+ 10 myuser mygroup 4096 Nov 14 20:29 log
```

When I execute the same exact commands directly from the terminal, it works OK. When I made a simple test.sh file and put the commands there, again it worked OK. So something must change when running the service script, but I'm not sure why. I also noticed that the script tries to determine the ACCESS_USER variable like so:

```
ACCESS_USER="$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')"
```

And it gets an empty result. But when I run the same command on my terminal, it prints "myuser" correctly. It also works from my test.sh file.

Where should I start? This is a certain product I'm using so I'll be sure to contact their support, but maybe I'll get some ideas from here also.

---

Edit: thanks for the comments, I'll try to answer.

@Chris Davies: $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG is /opt/myapp/home/domain/log/console.log, $JBOSS_HOME is /opt/myapp, I already shared the owners in my original question. Also thanks for the explanation between "whoami" and "who am i", I have read upon them before, but now it is clear that I need a terminal for "who am i" to work.

@waltinator and @muru: this script is not running from crontab, it is executed when I start the mentioned service: `sudo systemctl start myservice`, see the service description in my original question. The "myuser" user is added to the sudoers file so that it can launch the service.

@rivimey: I'm printing the output of the "id" command and the "whoami" command, it shows the correct user:

```
echo "id = $(id), whoami = $(whoami)

id = uid=1001(myuser) gid=1001(mygroup) groups=1001(mygroup) context=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0, whoami = myuser
```

Also when I check the running script in the "ps -ef" output, it also shows the correct user executing it.

---

Edit 2: ahh, it was SELinux... as I was typing my previous edit, I thought of disabling it, and now the service is working correctly. Strange, because I tried to check the audit logs, manually and with audit2allow command as well, I got some "missing type enforcement" rules, but nothing related to my application. If I don't get a better solution, I'll post this as answer.

Comment: The obvious question is what are the values of `$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG` and `$JBOSS_HOME`. The follow-up would be to ask what their permissions and owner/group are

Comment: Compare and contrast `who am i` (looks up the login session) and `whoami` (looks up the current user account). The first won't work unless you're actually logged in to a terminal

Comment: Not all of the variables are in double-quotes, and if any unquoted paths contain a space (or asterisk, or anything else the shell treats as special) the code will likely break

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script)

Comment: You mention sudo permissions, but I don't actually see sudo being used in the parts of the script shown.

Comment: suggest you run "id" command at the start of "service.sh" to check what that file is actually being run as. I suspect it's not what you expect.  Also, consider using 'strace' (with optional filtering via '-e') to see what errors are actually occurring on which files.

Comment: Please add the result of `ls -ld /opt/myapp /opt/myapp/home/domain/log/console.log` to your question