# Scheduling wine exe using cron job raises error

Tags: cron, python, wine

I have been trying to schedule an exe file which runs an underlying python script.

When I run it manually (`wine sample.exe`) on Debian Linux, it runs as expected, however when I run it using `cron`, it gives following error:

```
[45] Failed to start embedded python interpreter!
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
OSError: [WinError 6] Invalid handle

Current thread 0x0000002e (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

- Crontab Statement:

  ```
  35 12 * * 1 /home/user/sample/run_sample.sh > /home/user/sample/last_run.log 2>&1
  ```
- `run_sample.sh` contents:

  ```shell
  wine /home/user/sample/sample.exe
  ```

`sample.exe` is an exe file prepared using PyInstaller on a windows machine. It runs fine when manually triggered, only issue is running it with cron.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why crontab doesn't execute a scheduled bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script)

Comment: We need to see the job statement from your `crontab` file to answer this question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script doesn't answer my question as not sure which environment variable will solve this.

Added crontable job statement and file content.

Comment: Do you have a `bash` shebang at the top of your `run_sample.sh` script? A bash shebang would be this as the first line in your script: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: It didn't have shebang and that was the reason behind the error. Once I added this line, it worked smoothly with cron too. Thanks a lot!